# How to delete element from the list that a keyword in between the element in python

Tags: python

I have a list that contains elements and want to delete some elements that has particular keyword.

For example:

List contains:
list = ['red rose','blue rose','red color','yellow paper']

And I'm looking for deleting lists with keyword 'RED' and get output as

Output:    ['blue rose', 'yellow paper']

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list = ['red rose','blue rose','red color','yellow paper']
keyword = 'RED'
for i in list[:]:
    if i.find(keyword.lower()) != -1:
        list.remove(i)
print(list)
```

Comment: 1) Do not use the name of [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as a variable name. Just try `print(list("ABCD"))` at the end of your code to see, what I mean. 2) Do not delete list elements while iterating over it. Try your script with `['red rose','blue rose','red color', 'red ridignhood', 'yellow paper']` to illustrate the problem. 3) Please consider adding a description, when posting an answer. I suggest reading [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

There are primarily two ways of doing this:

Using list comprehension:

```
lst = ['red rose', 'blue rose', 'red color', 'yellow paper']

output = [i for i in lst if 'red' not in i.lower()]
```

Using a for loop:

```
lst = ['red rose', 'blue rose', 'red color', 'yellow paper']

output = []
for i in lst:
    if 'red' not in i.lower():
        output.append(i)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

All what you need is a loop:

```
s =  ['red rose','blue rose','red color','yellow paper']
s = [x for x in s if not str(x).lower().__contains__('red')]
print(s)
```

> > ['blue rose', 'yellow paper']

Comment: Thank you. This is cool. But, do you have any other alternate logic?

Comment: Do you want to solve your issue or you need a new logic ?!

Comment: I need logic sir.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> foo = ['red rose','blue rose','red color','yellow paper']

>>> [x for x in foo if 'red' not in x]
['blue rose', 'yellow paper']
```

This of course assumes lower case letters.
And note it doesn't delete entries, but rather creates a new list object.

Comment: Why the downvote??

Comment: Hey, I dint do this in intention. I clicked up arrow but it still says -1. Sorry